# While converting a PIL image into a tensor why the pixels are changing?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, python-imaging-library, kaggle

```py
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToPILImage(), transforms.ToTensor()])
```

**Before applying the transformation**

> [image: Before applying the transformation]

**After applying the transformation**

> [image: After applying the transformation]

Q.1 Why the pixel values are changed?
Q.2 How to correct this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by normalizing the input data before transforming it.
The problem was that `ToPILImage()` was discarding all the values which were greater than 1 hence the bright pixels became dark.

Comment: Could you post the code here, please? That link is dead.

Comment: Sorry for the VERY late reply, I wasn't active on SO for some time.
Also unfortunately I don't have the code now, although iirc i just normalized the input image using [transforms.Normalize](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.Normalize.html) @CrazyChucky

Answer (score 4):

Q1: transforms.ToTensor() of torchvision normalizes your input image, i.e. puts it in the range [0,1] as it is a very common preprocessing step.

Q2: use `torch.tensor(input_image)` to convert image into a tensor instead.

Comment: It doesn't work, and even if transforms.ToTensor() normalizes the input image the relative values of pixels should not change, but the bright pixels become completely dark when performing the transform.